# Problems with styling UserControl

Tags: wpf, xaml, user-controls

I have created an UserControl that actauly just a closeable tabItem (In code its inherit TabItem) And just cannot figure out how to style it in right way

```
 <UserControl x:Class="CloseableHeader"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" Margin="0" d:Height="32" d:Width="112" >
    <Grid>
        <Button  Height="21" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Name="button_close" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="24" FontFamily="Courier" FontWeight="Bold" Style="{StaticResource {x:Static ToolBar.ButtonStyleKey}}" FontStretch="Normal" Visibility="Visible" FontSize="14" Padding="0" ToolTip="Close" Margin="0,5,5,0">
            <Image Height="19" Width="20" RenderTransformOrigin="0.45,0.5" Source="close.png"/>

        </Button>
        <Label Content="TabItem"  Height="28" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="4,2,0,0" Name="label_TabTitle" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontFamily="Verdana" FontSize="14.667" Foreground="#FD000000" />
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

[image]
Please tell me why backgound is still white? It should be transparent.

Comment: `UserControl that actauly just a closeable tabItem (In code its inherit TabItem)` - You're doing it all wrong. Also, Don't subclass WPF UI elements unless you have a `good` reason to do so. Adding some content into a `TabItem` is NOT a `good` reason to subclass `TabItem`. Learn MVVM.

Comment: well hoped code project is good source :) HEre the article for this tabitem: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/84213/How-to-add-a-Close-button-to-a-WPF-TabItem
And btw mvvm? I need styling not programming I think.. thanks for response anyway

Comment: My point is that you don't need to subclass `TabItem` for this. And if your class inherits from that, how come your XAML is defined as `<UserControl>`? You need to go back to basic C# and OOP to understand what a class is, and how inheritance works.

Comment: Well I was looked for tbaitem like this and just found this article http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/84213/How-to-add-a-Close-button-to-a-WPF-TabItem. So do you have any ideas how to actualy fix this?

Comment: Dude, that code in codeproject is `horrible`. I suggest you create a proper ViewModel to handle the closing logic and use a `DataTemplate` to define the TabItems Content.